# Pointer of a function with variable number of arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a function with the following prototype:

```
void func(int an, ...);
```

And I would like to store the adress of this function and call it later.
I have really no idea to how to do that, I desesperatly tried :

```
void (*funcPtr)(int, ...);  // Declaration
funcPtr = func;     // Storage
(*funcPtr)(3,2,5);      // Call
```

This code compiles fine, but at execution it does crap, when I enter my function the arguments in my `va_list` are not the ones I sent.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :** Alright, I just forgot the first argument. In my code above, the call line should be replaced with:

```
(*funcPtr)(3,3,2,5);        // Call
```

Comment: Looks fine here: http://ideone.com/uqLLR5.

Comment: Very strange, your code doesn't work for me, like my old one: compiles fine but arguments are not the ones expected. I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Out of curiosity, what values is Oli's code displaying?

Comment: @LoveMetal, Please include a segment of code that implements 'va_list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are pointers naturally.  So you can simply call:

```
funcPtr(3,3,2,5);
```

It looks like you have everything right.  If the function does not have variable arguments, it is a really good idea to declare the function pointer with the right "shape" of arguments for protection from passing malformed arguments.